# Validate Zip Code Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to validate that zip codes are valid for users.  I am using the Zend Framework 2.  The form field type is 'text' (I have tried value options but it does not seem to work for the text element).  Is there a way I can validate this on the form or in the model (input filter)?  I have a list of zip codes in the database so I can use an inArray check in the controller but would like to include it in the model or form if possible.  Thanks

Comment: [The documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.post-code.html#postcode-validator) should be the first place you look.

Comment: But does this validate if a zip code is real?  It seems like 11111 would pass.  I want to insure it is a real zip code (exists in my database)

Answer (score 1):

```
may be you can write a class in Form folder extend Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator (exmple: zipcodeCheck) and you must implements the function isValid(), you can create some REGEX statement such like :
public function isValid($value){
if(!preg_match('\d{5}([ -]\d{4})?', $value)){// $value is the data you want to validate
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

and your Filter must add:

```
$this->add(array(
           'name'        => 'zipcode',
           'validators'  => array(
               array(
                     'name'       => '\Mmc\Form\yourClassName',//zipcodeCheck may be
                     'options'    => array(
                             'error_title'  => 'Zipcode From',
                    )
               )
           ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 validates the given postal code based on predefined REGEX patterns (for US region they use following REGEX pattern **'\d{5}([ -]\d{4})?'**).

So, ZF2 always returns TRUE, if you pass **11111**.

Thanks